# How to render this json in view laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Good morning ! I have a problem which the following json , I recieve this

```
{"id":51,"nif":"","name":"","cognoms":"","file":"uploads\/$usuario->id\/$fileName","birthday":"0000-00-00","presentacion":"desde","email":"pepes@pepepefgpepepep.com","idempresa":1,"id_poblacion":826,"id_online":0,"created_at":"2015-05-23 23:53:46","updated_at":"2015-05-23 23:53:46","municipio":{"id":826,"idprovincia":29,"poblacion":"Castellitx","poblacionseo":"castellitx","postal":7210,"latitud":"39.562691","longitud":"2.882967"},"bids":[{"id":36,"nombre":"asdsfasd","descripcion":"fsdafsdafsdfsa","precio_salida":170,"cant_actual":172,"id_estado":1,"id_metode_envio":2,"id_metodo_pago":1,"id_creador":51,"id_ganador":null,"id_categoria":34,"id_adquirido":0,"data_inici":"2015-05-30","durada":null,"created_at":"2015-05-24 19:06:19","updated_at":"2015-05-24 20:26:56"}]}<p>233.81707298156</p> {"id":37,"nif":"","name":"","cognoms":"","file":"uploads\/claves.png","birthday":"2015-05-05","presentacion":"asdasdasfafsadfa","email":"","idempresa":1,"id_poblacion":23,"id_online":0,"created_at":"2015-05-22 09:16:33","updated_at":"2015-05-25 08:40:03","municipio":{"id":23,"idprovincia":1,"poblacion":"Barrundia","poblacionseo":"barrundia","postal":1206,"latitud":"42.917229","longitud":"-2.495040"},"bids":[{"id":37,"nombre":"asdffsa","descripcion":"fsadfsdafa","precio_salida":187,"cant_actual":187,"id_estado":1,"id_metode_envio":1,"id_metodo_pago":1,"id_creador":37,"id_ganador":null,"id_categoria":34,"id_adquirido":0,"data_inici":"0000-00-00","durada":null,"created_at":"2015-05-24 19:07:26","updated_at":"2015-05-24 19:07:26"},{"id":38,"nombre":"dsfsdafdsfas","descripcion":"asdfdsagafgfdga","precio_salida":190,"cant_actual":190,"id_estado":1,"id_metode_envio":2,"id_metodo_pago":1,"id_creador":37,"id_ganador":null,"id_categoria":35,"id_adquirido":0,"data_inici":"0000-00-00","durada":null,"created_at":"2015-05-24 19:08:01","updated_at":"2015-05-24 19:08:01"},{"id":39,"nombre":"vcxvcvzxc","descripcion":"sdvzxvcxvz","precio_salida":300,"cant_actual":300,"id_estado":1,"id_metode_envio":2,"id_metodo_pago":1,"id_creador":37,"id_ganador":null,"id_categoria":33,"id_adquirido":0,"data_inici":"0000-00-00","durada":null,"created_at":"2015-05-24 19:08:27","updated_at":"2015-05-24 19:08:27"}]}<p>420.31608445891</p>
```

When I use the foreach with this form , the information shows correct

```
@foreach ($output as $auction)
    @if(count($auction> 0))
        {{$auction}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

However , when I call at , the Laravel show an error.

```
{{$auction->auctions}}
```

I don't know whi when I put {{$auction->auctions}} laravel return an error , could anybody help my with this ? Is OneToMany relationships.

The controller to recieve this json is this

```
public function prodcercanos($lat,$long)
    {

        $cercanos = User::with('municipio')->with('subastas')->get();
        $coordA   = Geotools::coordinate([$lat,$long]); 
        $output = [];
        foreach ($cercanos as $p) {
            if(count($p->subastas)>0){
            $coordB   = Geotools::coordinate([$p->municipio->latitud,$p->municipio->longitud]);
            $distance = Geotools::distance()->setFrom($coordA)->setTo($coordB);
            $dis = $distance->in('km')->haversine();
            $output[$dis] = $p."<p>$dis</p>";
            }
        }       
            ksort($output);

        return view('frontend.prodcercanos2')->with('output',$output)
```

Comment: You have to commit eager loaded object to your view, see http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading (works quite the same in L4 btw.) but your code seems to hae some other issues. could you try to make your question a bit clearer? (what are you trying to do, what have you tried, what is the expected outcome, what does it acually do, error details etc..)

Comment: I put the controller , I don't know how to render in the view I think...

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, the object types are not maintained. Calling `$auction->auction` will not yield any results, because the `auction` object is probably from the type `StdObject`.

Also, I don't know if this is a typo in your code pasted or just a typo in your live code, but this:

`@if(count($auction> 0))`

Will not work. You have got the comparison operator (`>`) inside your `count()` function.